# What to do if nostril closed while doing ajapa japa?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, yoga, yoga-sutras

I was practicing ajapa japa daily till I got fever&cough a few days ago after getting well I started it again but my nostrils close which destroy the rythm and produce a very unpleasant soundwhenever I try to do it any solution?

Comment: Nadi sodham Pranayama after waking up in the morning and emptying bowels.

Comment: First, it is not unusual for your sinuses to remain stuffed for a week or two after recovering from illness. Second, when you are completely well, 'drink' a little water through each nostril before starting.